# Covariant Return Type in Interface not compiling via Javac

Tags: java, eclipse, javac, covariant

I have the following structure:

```
public interface BarReturn {}
public interface FooReturn {}
public interface FooBarReturn extends FooReturn, BarReturn {}

public interface Foo {  
  FooReturn fooBar( );
}

public interface Bar {
  BarReturn fooBar();
}

public interface FooBar extends Foo, Bar {
  FooBarReturn fooBar();
}
```

Javac fails with the following message:

```
FooBar.java:2: types Bar and Foo are incompatible; both define fooBar(), but with unrelated return types
public interface FooBar extends Foo, Bar {
       ^
1 error
```

However, Eclipse can compile it fine, and as far as I can see it should compile - FooBar's fooBar() method satisfies the contract of both Foo and Bar's fooBar() method by using covariant returns.

Is this a bug in the Eclipse compile or in javac?  Or is there a way to persuade javac to compile it?  For reference my javac options look like this:

```
javac -d /tmp/covariant/target/classes -sourcepath /tmp/covariant/src/main/java: /tmp/covariant/src/main/java/Foo.java /tmp/covariant/src/main/java/BarReturn.java /tmp/covariant/src/main/java/FooBarReturn.java /tmp/covariant/src/main/java/Bar.java /tmp/covariant/src/main/java/FooReturn.java /tmp/covariant/src/main/java/FooBar.java -g -nowarn -target 1.6 -source 1.6
```

Comment: Same problem with open-jdk compiler version 1.6.0_22. but it works in java7.

Comment: Just tested it and yes, so it does - great.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343238/java-implementing-multiple-interfaces-with-same-method-and-different-return-ty)?

Answer (score 3):

You are extending both Foo and Bar in your FooBar interface. As such you are inheriting two methods with incompatible return types. Java co-variance is only allowed when it follows Liskov substitution. Aka, the overriding candidate types must pretty much be a subclass of the overridden return type.

In your example above something like this *should* compile:

```
public interface BarReturn {}
public interface FooReturn {}
public interface FooBarReturn extends FooReturn, BarReturn {}

public interface Foo {  
  FooReturn fooBar( );
}

public interface FooBar extends Foo{
  FooBarReturn fooBar();
}
```

Comment: In the OP's code, the return type of the overriding method *does* subtype the return types of both overridden methods. So from an academic standpoint, there's no reason why the OP's code shouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 1):

[The JLS (§9.4.1)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.4.1) says :

> It is possible for an interface to inherit several methods with
>   override-equivalent signatures (§8.4.2). Such a situation does not in
>   itself cause a compile-time error. The interface is considered to
>   inherit all the methods. However, one of the inherited methods must
>   must be return type substitutable for any other inherited method;
>   otherwise, a compile-time error occurs (The throws clauses do not
>   cause errors in this case.)

So I would say that javac is right. But this looks like lawyer jargon to me, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An answer in this [javaranch discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/457998/java/java/Covariance-multiple-interface-inheritance) seems to suggest that it's a javac bug.  However, the referenced [bug url](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6294779) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It seems like [JDK-7u4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html) fixes the bug.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could do

```
interface Foo1 extends Foo {
  FooBarReturn fooBar();
}
interface Bar1 extends Bar {
  FooBarReturn fooBar();
}
public interface FooBar extends Foo1, Bar1 { }
```

Not pretty but should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea - however, as it compiles with OpenJDK 7's javac and with the eclipse compiler I can work around it without introducing extra types.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, jdk6's javac still says `types Bar1 and Foo1 are incompatible; both define fooBar(), but with unrelated return types`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it seems to be fine by using the JDK 7 from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in Sun's Java 6 compiler](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6908259).