# Java - implementing multiple interfaces with same method and different return types

Tags: java, interface, overriding, jls

Consider the following code:

```
public interface A {
  public A another();
}

public interface B {
  public B another();
}

public interface AB extends A,B {
  public AB another();
}
```

This leads to a compile error on `AB`:

> types B and A are incompatible; both define another(), but with
>   unrelated return types

I've seen this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implemeting-2-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method-is-o), and follow the incompatibility example in the the accepted answer - i.e.

```
public interface C { 
  public void doSomething();
}

public interface D {
  public boolean doSomething();
}

public interface CD extends C,D { 
}
```

However, in that case the return types were genuinely incompatible - a return type cannot be both void and a boolean. Whereas, in my example above, the `another()` return type of `AB` is both an `A` and a `B`, so it is possible to implement both of the extended interfaces.

Furthermore, having looked at the JLS (8.4.8, 8.4.8.3, 8.4.8.4), I don't quite understand why my example above illegal. Can anyone explain this to me?

Second, are there any solutions/workarounds to this other than repeating the contract requirements of `A` or `B` in `AB`?

Comment: The code you have provided should compile fine, Are you sure you have `return AB another();` in you `AB` interface? return type should be `AB` otherwise it won't compile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error message appears for pre 1.5 versions of Java (at least I can reproduce the error when setting the compliance level to 1.4 in Eclipse). In other words, make sure you're looking at old-enough specs.

On Java >= 1.5 the following compiles fine.

```
interface A {
    public A another();
}

interface B {
    public B another();
}

interface AB extends A,B {
    public AB another();
}
```

As you say, since `AB` is both an `A` and a `B`, it satisfies both interfaces.

---

Here's a quote from the Java Language Specification (Second Edition, i.e. Java 1.4):

> **9.2 Interface Members**
>
> The members of an interface are:
>
> - Those members declared in the interface.
> - Those **members inherited from direct superinterfaces**.
> - If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, [...]
>
> It follows that it is a compile-time error if the interface **declares a method with the same signature and different return type** or incompatible throws clause.

Further more, the *current* spec says the following:

> **9.4.2 Overloading**
>
> If two methods of an interface (whether both declared in the same interface, or both inherited by an interface, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but different signatures that are not override-equivalent (§8.4.2), then the method name is said to be overloaded. This fact causes no difficulty and never of itself results in a compile-time error. There is no required relationship between the return types or between the throws clauses of two methods with the same name but different signatures that are not override-equivalent.

Comment: I was compiling with 1.6 (in an IDE). I just tried compiling this with jdk 1.6.0_30 on the command line, and got the same compiler error. However, it did sucessfully compile with 1.7.0_1.

Comment: That's interesting. If the behavior differs I bet there's a bug report on either of the two compilers.

Comment: Did you get this code to compile - if so, which java version were you using?

Comment: I compiled it using Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: According to the discussion [here (Eclipse JDT bug report)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122881) it's a javac bug.

Comment: Thanks - that strongly suggests it was a javac bug. Indeed, one of the comments on that bug report was that this issue had also been raised with Sun, but my searches in the Sun/Oracle bug database couldn't find it. So... maybe it's time to switch to Java 7...