# Generics Compile Time error

Tags: java, generics

This is from a complex build system. And I am looking for help to localize the problem.

It seems like I am hitting this problem: [Covariant Return Type in Interface not compiling via Javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056485/covariant-return-type-in-interface-not-compiling-via-javac)

My code compiles fine when I compile after cleaning all compiled code. But if I open `AImpl.java` and change one character (modify any string literal, which shouldn't generate any compile time error) and compile then I get following error:

```
AImpl.java:22: types BImpl<T> and BImpl<T> are incompatible; both define waitFor(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition,java.lang.String,long,java.util.Collection), but with unrelated return types
public class AImpl<T extends AImpl<T>> extends BImpl<T> implements A<T> {
```

This is specific to AImpl.java ; changing any other code doesn't generate this vicious error.

`BImpl.java` is defined as:

```
public class BImpl<T extends BImpl<T>> extends CImpl<T> implements B<T> {
```

The erroring method `waitFor` is defined in `CImpl` as:

```
public T waitFor(ExpectedCondition<?> condition, String message, long timeOutInMillis, Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>> exceptions)
```

Comment: Can you show us your classes/interfaces, please?

Comment: More specifically, what are the return types of the two `waitFor` interface definitions?

Comment: @TimS. i provided more context in the question.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Please make a short but complete example. In particular, you're saying that the error is in CImpl, but the error message says it's in AImpl.

Comment: The error message is correct and my question is consistent. I am saying that the error appears in AImpl, but the erroring method in inherited by AImpl and BImpl from CImpl (AImpl > BImpl > CImpl).

Comment: It's consistent, maybe, but it's far from being complete. We can't see the code that you have on your screen. If you don't want to be helped, definitely leave the question as it is.

Comment: @JBNizet i am not sure what will be helpful. The classes are big and complex and I am trying to paste the portions which are relevant to the error.

Comment: well, wild guess here, but how about the above extended so that it can be compiled and people can see the error themselves?  maybe i am crazy and all, but that seems like it might help.  no?

Comment: Thanks. I will try to make a similar but simpler hierarchy and post the code here; if it can reproduce the problem. I am hoping for the wild guesses as this problem is intermittent. Compiling from a clean build succeeds while recompiling after a trivial change fails.